# How can I debug a Unity3D Android app via WiFi

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine

If I use Android Studio I can debug an app by doing the following

1. Connect device via USB
2. In a console type: ADB tcpip 5555
3. ADB connect (ip address of device)
4. Disconnect USB

Now ADB sees the device and Android Studio will let use it to debug.

What I need to do is debug Unity3D projects on this device, but it still only seems to debug devices that are connected via USB. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes in android it worked by this way.

Comment: Did u ever figure this out?

Comment: @user1767754 I don't think I did, no